# Checkedlistbox Multicolumn

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multiple-columns, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox` control in Windows Forms.

I want to know who to add multi-columns to it.
The `MultiColumn` property is set to true.
I just want to know the coding to add 2 columns.

The code I have is

```
while (true)
{
    data = SDK.GetNext("ACCHISTL", 6);
    document_details = data.Split('|');
    if (document_details[0] == "0")
    {
        if (document_details[3] == Document_nr)
        {
            lbLines.Items.su(document_details[4] + " -> " + document_details[14],true);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Can you please assist me on show me the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Side note: change `running  = false` to `break` and `while(running)` to `while(true)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Tank you man. I have change that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although `CheckedListBox` has `MultiColumn` property and you can set it to true, but it only arranges list of items in multiple columns flowing items top to down then right, based on height of control

```
■ 1         ■ 5
■ 2         ■ 6
■ 3         ■ 7
■ 4
```

So if you really need multiple column, consider using `DatGridView` or `ListView` that are real multi column controls.

Comment: Thank you for your information :) I have change it to a DataGridView and it is working 100% now

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `MultiColumn` property to true doesn't allow you to add more columns manually. It just 'wraps' items to the next column instead of showing a vertical scrollbar once the items exceed the height of the `CheckedListBox`.

If you want a two column control, either use a grid control of some kind or a `ListView` control. By setting a `ListView` control's `View` property to `View.Details`, you can use it as a multicolumn 'grid'.

Comment: I have change my CheckboxList to a ListView. Will see if it works then let you know. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yeah, let me know how that goes. I've been experimenting with CheckedListBoxes too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TableLayoutPanel with desired number of columns and rows and put the checkboxes in there.